# Using vgridshift from Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geometry, utm, pyproj

When running the following code:-

```
outProj = Proj("+proj=vgridshift +grids=dvr90.gtx")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Input is not a CRS: +proj=vgridshift +grids=dvr90.gtx +type=crs
```

I am trying to convert from lat/long to ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N + DVR90.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Transformer.from_pipeline](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline):

```py
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> tr = Transformer.from_pipeline("+proj=vgridshift +grids=dvr90.gtx")
>>> tr
<Other Coordinate Operation Transformer: vgridshift>
Description: PROJ-based coordinate operation
Area of Use:
- undefined
>>> tr.definition
'proj=vgridshift grids=dvr90.gtx ellps=GRS80'
```